# Why is a custom angular directive not disabled with ng-disabled set to true

Tags: angularjs-directive, accessibility

I have been playing around with ngAria and ngDisabled in AngularJS using the example given [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility) .I modified the custom-checkbox directive in the example to set ng-disabled= true in the controller , that further sets aria-disabled=true as seen in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVEi3w?p=preview)  output here.

```
<some-checkbox role="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-class="{active: checked}" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="toggleCheckbox()" aria-label="Custom Checkbox" show-attrs>
    var app = angular.module('ngAria_ngModelExample', ['ngAria'])     
   .controller('formsController', function($scope){
    $scope.checked = false;
    $scope.isDisabled=true;
    $scope.toggleCheckbox = function(){
    $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
    }
  })...
```

But with ng-disabled=true and aria-disabled=true this does not disable the "Custom Checkbox" as seen in the plunker output. 
As per the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility#ngdisabled) and several examples on stackoverflow, the "disabled" attribute works only for buttons, input and text area. For custom directives (like the one above), ngDisabled is the way to go. But it does not seem to work for the above example. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The disabled attribute is only valid for certain elements such as button, input and textarea

`ngDisabled` adds or removes the disabled attribute to your element. I suggest you watch the disabled expression in your custom directive, and add / remove a class to disable your component.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating your own component that you want to have support for ng-disabled, then you can add this inside $onInit after injecting $attrs and $parse:

```js
// Watch ng-disabled
this.$scope.$watch(
  () => {
    let value = this.$attrs.ngDisabled;
    // Evaluate ng-disabled expression on parent scope
    let evaluated = this.$scope.$parent.$eval(value);
    return evaluated;
  },
  (disabled) => {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As with all ARIA controls, the browser does not give you any "behavior" for free. What the addition of roles like "button" does is it instructs the browser/screen-reader what to do with announcements and what to do with keyboard events. What I mean by "what to do with keyboard events", this means "switch to-or-from forms mode automatically when the element receives focus".

This means that you need to:

1. Implement event handlers for keyboard and mouse/touch commands,
2. Implement the visual styling to convey the state of the component
   (e.g. disabled, enabled or selected, not selected etc.), and
3. Implement the interpretation of the state (so disable the keyboard and
   touch/mouse handling when the state is disabled)